# How to set a variable to a column with no header in a tab delimited text file

Tags: powershell, columnheader, csv

```
Barcode1     Plate #    12/29/2017 07:35:56 EST
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
A            1          4                              5          6
```

Above is an example of a tab delimited text file. I need to get the data from the column with no header; namely, the columns at the end and I don't know how to identify it. I am trying to swap columns and output a text file. The source data file format is the same every time.
This is part of what I have:

```
$swapColumns = @{
    column1  = @{
        name     = "date-header"
        instance = 1
    }
    column2 = @{
        name     = "Blank"
        instance = 1
    }
}
$formats = @(
    'XR-{0:yyyyMMdd}-01.txt'
)
$date = [datetime]::now

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

function Get-HeaderIndex {
    param(
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$Source,
        [string]$Header,
        [uint16]$Instance
    )
    $index = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Instance; $i++) {
        $index = $Source.IndexOf($Header, $index, ($Source.Count - $index))
        if (($index -eq -1) -or (($i + 1) -eq $Instance)) {
        break
        }
        $index = $index + 1
    }
    if ($index -eq -1) { throw "index not found" }
    return $index
}

#grabs the first item in folder matching UCX-*.txt
$fileDetails = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\UCX-*.txt | select -First 1 

#gets the file contents
$file = Get-Content $fileDetails

#break up script in sections that look like '======section======'
#and store the section name and line number it starts on
$sections = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $file.Count; $i++) {
    if ($file[$i] -match '^=+(\w+)=+$') {
        $section = $Matches[1]
        $sections += [pscustomobject]@{line = $i; header = $section}
    }
}

#get the data section
$dataSection = $sections | ? {$_.header -eq 'data'}

#get the section following data
$nextSection = $sections | ? {$_.line -gt $dataSection.line} | sort 
-Property line | select -First 1
#get data column headers

$dataHeaders = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$file[$dataSection.line + 1].split("`t") | % {
    [datetime]$headerDateValue = [datetime]::MinValue
    $headerIsDate = [datetime]::TryParse($_.Replace('EST','').Trim(), 
    [ref] $headerDateValue)
    if ($headerIsDate) {
        $dataHeaders.Add('date-header')
    }
    else {
        $dataHeaders.Add($_)
    }
}

#get index of columns defined in $swapColumns
$column1 = Get-HeaderIndex -Source $dataHeaders -Header 
    $swapColumns.column1.name -Instance $swapColumns.column1.instance
$column2 = Get-HeaderIndex -Source $dataHeaders -Header 
    swapColumns.column2.name -Instance $swapColumns.column2.instance

#iterate over each row in data section, swap data from column1/column2
for ($i = $dataSection.line + 2; $i -lt $nextSection.line - 1; $i++) {
    $line = $file[$i]
    $parts = $line.split("`t")
    $tmp1 = $parts[$column1]
    $parts[$column1] = $parts[$column2]
    $parts[$column2] = $tmp1
    $file[$i] = $parts -join "`t"
}

#write new file contents to files with names defined in $formats
$formats | % { 
    $file | Out-File ($_ -f $date) -Force
}
```

Comment: The column example did not format correctly :(
It's a simple table of data with column headers, except one of the columns has no heading.

Comment: Is your source data header probably tab delimited so between "Plate #               12/29/2017 07:35:56 EST" there is actually 2 tabs? Its just missing a name?

Comment: In the text file itself there is one tab between each heading. But I opened the text file with excel to identify which heading actually went with which column. In which case I found that some data columns did not have a heading. The code works for all the columns with headings. I apologize that I'm not using the correct terminology to explain. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know what the columns are all supposed to be ahead of time? Their names and order I mean.

Comment: Or perhaps some semblance of header order.... I see you have a date column that is likely to change but is it always the "4th" column

Comment: I've updated the post. The columns are always the same except for the date that changes, which I've resolved.

Comment: There's way too much code in your question and your exact requirements are being revealed over time. You'll have better luck if you ask a focused question based on an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you know what your file format is going to be then forget whatever the current header is and assume when we convert the file to a CSV object.

It looks like you need to parse the date of out the header which should be trivial. Grab it from `$fileheader` however you would like.

```
$wholeFile = Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt
$fileHeader = $wholeFile[0] -split "`t"
$newHeader = "Barcode1", "Plate #", "Date", "Plumbus", "Dinglebop"

$wholeFile |Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header $newHeader
```

Comment: OK the whole text file is not tab delimited and in columns. Just that data section is.

Comment: @Johnnyc The text of the question and provided example in no way suggests that. Does the "Data" section have start and stop keywords or anything.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer doesn't solve the OP's problem after clarifying the exact  requirements, but may be of general interest to some, given the question's generic title.]

If the file is really *tab*-delimited, you can use `` Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `` to read it, in which case PowerShell will autogenerate header names as `H<n>` if they're missing, where `<n>` is a sequence number starting with `1`.

*Caveat*: This doesn't work if the unnamed column is the *last* one, because - inexplicably - `Import-Csv` then ignores the entire column (more generally, any run of trailing delimiters).

```
 Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" file.tsv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty H1
```

Comment: the caveat for this is if the blank column is at the end though right?

Comment: The blank column is at the end. And there are more than 1 blank columns.

Comment: I am used to that behaviour. It bases how it treats the data based on the header so I suppose it can't guess?

Comment: @Matt: If an empty _internal_ header field is recognized as such, I see no reason why a _trailing_ one shouldn't be, but in practice any run of trailing delimiters is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns length is always the same, there's another option, specify manually the width of the columns, See example:

```
$content = Get-Content C:\temp.tsv

$columns = 13, 24, 35 | Sort -Descending
$Delimiter = ','

  $Results = $content | % {
  $line = $_
  $columns | % {
    $line = $line.Insert($_, $Delimiter)  
  }
  $line
} |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $Delimiter
```

Results:

```
Barcode1  Plate #     H1 12/29/2017 07:35:56 EST
--------- ----------- -- -----------------------
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5                      
A         1           4  5
```

Then you can easily get the data you need:

```
$Results[0].H1
4
```